# Thunderbird 52.2.1 -- are scripts being run from emails?

Tags: email, thunderbird

I don't like not knowing what someone is taking from or doing to my computer.

I've used Thunderbird for years.  Maybe I never noticed, but on some emails I notice a progress bar running at the bottom of the message.  Some run longer than others.  The Mail toolbar has an X in a circle that stops the progress bar.  When I set it to View/Message Body As/Simple HTML, I don't see the progress bar.

What is the progress bar for?  Searches indicate that javascript is not enabled for email messages.  Is something else going on?

Comment: If you're worried about security, you can disable remote content in messages: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/remote-content-in-messages

Comment: JavaScript has been disabled in e-mail since Thunderbird 3. Strange things can be done with allowed image objects. Not only can the sender track who reads the email by looking at unique image loads on their web server but an image itself could trigger odd behavior in the OS if there is a vulnerability in the way the image is handled. It's best to not load images from e-mail. The progress bar has many uses. Hard to tell what you are seeing.